# Timezone of now in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, timezone

What is the timezone of elasticsearch when I use now ?

```
{
   "range": {
      "myDateInSomeTimezone": {
         "gt": "now"
      }
   }
},
```

I am wondering what is the timezone of now:

- is with my server local timezone?
- is with same timezone of the field?
- is with UTC timezone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`now` is always resolved to [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)  in millisecond. 
 So one would need to either store the dates in UTC or speicify the timezone parameter in the range query.

From the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) :

> Dates can be converted from another timezone to UTC either by
>   specifying the time zone in the date value itself (if the format
>   accepts it), or it can be specified as the time_zone parameter:
>
> now is not affected by the time_zone parameter (dates must be stored
>   as UTC).

Comment: I have a similar problem, and looking for a way to tell  ES that consider now in my current timezone not UTC, do you know how can I tell ES to consider now in my timezone in all queries that ES handle?

Comment: This is my problem too, for tests the Timezone are using user machine TZ :(

Comment: The dates are already stored in UTC, in ElasticSearch

Answer (score 4):

`now` by itself will query based on UTC. So querying documents from midnight UTC to now would look like:

```
         "range" =>  {
            "myDateInSomeTimezone" =>  {
              "gte" =>  "now/d",
              "lte" =>  "now"
            }
          }
```

If you want to query documents in timezone other than UTC, you can use the `time_zone` parameter to the range queries like this:

```
         "range" =>  {
            "myDateInSomeTimezone" =>  {
              "gte" =>  "now/d",
              "lte" =>  "now",
              "time_zone" =>  "America/Los_Angeles"
            }
          }
```

Comment: `time_zone` does not affect `now`, which is always in UTC